# DB2 for IBM i: Missing sql_function

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

A customer cannot use the offset-clause
(https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=subselect-offset-clause), although having V7R2.

My guess is that the sql_function isn't installed.

Is there a way a view to check for installed system functions ?

And how can you install the function/sql_package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PTF SF99702 Level 19 is needed, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/1164532).

Check installed level with

```
wrkptfgrp sf99702
```